# External HDD disconnects when formating. Disk or SATA-to-USB adapter problem?

Tags: usb, external-hdd, mkfs, sata

My SATA HD used as an external disk connected to a USB port is not working. When I try to format it using `sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdj1`, I get: "Input/output error while writing out and closing file system".

In `dmesg`, I see

```
[ 3819.478357] usb 4-3: USB disconnect, device number 47
[ 3819.478535] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: WARN Set TR Deq Ptr cmd failed due to incorrect slot or ep state.
[ 3819.498268] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdj, sector 487239680 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x4000 phys_seg 256 prio class 0
[ 3819.498366] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdj, sector 487241728 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x4000 phys_seg 256 prio class 0
[ 3819.498432] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdj, sector 2048 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 8 prio class 0
[ 3819.498444] Buffer I/O error on dev sdj1, logical block 0, lost async page write
[ 3819.498450] Buffer I/O error on dev sdj1, logical block 1, lost async page write
[ 3819.498453] Buffer I/O error on dev sdj1, logical block 2, lost async page write
[ 3819.498455] Buffer I/O error on dev sdj1, logical block 3, lost async page write
[ 3819.498458] Buffer I/O error on dev sdj1, logical block 4, lost async page write
[ 3819.498461] Buffer I/O error on dev sdj1, logical block 5, lost async page write
[ 3819.498463] Buffer I/O error on dev sdj1, logical block 6, lost async page write
[ 3819.498466] Buffer I/O error on dev sdj1, logical block 7, lost async page write
[ 3819.498514] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdj, sector 487243776 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x4000 phys_seg 256 prio class 0
[ 3819.500108] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdj, sector 2528 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x4800 phys_seg 2048 prio class 0
[ 3819.500114] Buffer I/O error on dev sdj1, logical block 480, lost async page write
[ 3819.500117] Buffer I/O error on dev sdj1, logical block 481, lost async page write
[ 3819.500927] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdj, sector 487245824 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x4000 phys_seg 256 prio class 0
[ 3819.502469] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdj, sector 4576 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x4800 phys_seg 2048 prio class 0
[ 3819.503514] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdj, sector 487247872 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x4000 phys_seg 256 prio class 0
[ 3819.505103] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdj, sector 6624 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x4800 phys_seg 2048 prio class 0
[ 3819.505902] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdj, sector 487249920 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x4000 phys_seg 256 prio class 0
[ 3819.742439] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdj] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[ 3819.742459] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdj] Synchronize Cache(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 3820.014442] usb 4-3: new SuperSpeed USB device number 48 using xhci_hcd
```

I can I find out if the problem lies on the disk or in the SATA-to-USB adapter if I don't have other disks and adapters to test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could be down to a bad USB cable or/and insufficient/missing external power source. Some USB ports are simply too underpowered to drive a HDD.

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, it was simply down to a bad USB cable. For future readers: if your USB port is underpowered, you can try a USB Y-cable.

Comment: Insufficient power from the host bus can manifest in other ways, too, such as during device initialization. Kernel error messages might include things like `Read Capacity(10) failed`, `Sense Key : Illegal Request [current]`, and `Add. Sense: Invalid command operation code`. [I had this problem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/749838/read-capacity10-failed-and-sense-key-illegal-request-with-a-sata-to-usb) with a 2.5" SATA magnetic disk, and using a different SATA-to-USB adapter with mains power solved the problem for me.