# "Read Capacity(10) failed" and "Sense Key : Illegal Request" with a SATA-to-USB adapter

Tags: linux, usb-drive, storage, dmesg, sata

What is the meaning of these error messages in the system log, when I plug in [a 2.5" spinning-disk SATA drive](https://www.seagate.com/files/staticfiles/support/docs/samsung-ds/100698122c.pdf) that I *know* works, using a [USB-to-SATA adapter](https://web.archive.org/web/20230401071626/https://sabrent.com/products/ec-ss31)?

```
Jun 25 16:08:07 hostname kernel: [181603.928983] scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     SABRENT                   2210 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
Jun 25 16:08:07 hostname kernel: [181603.931640] sd 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
Jun 25 16:08:07 hostname kernel: [181603.938380] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
Jun 25 16:08:07 hostname kernel: [181603.938391] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense Key : Illegal Request [current]
Jun 25 16:08:07 hostname kernel: [181603.938398] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Add. Sense: Invalid command operation code
Jun 25 16:08:07 hostname kernel: [181603.939443] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] 0 512-byte logical blocks: (0 B/0 B)
Jun 25 16:08:07 hostname kernel: [181603.939449] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] 0-byte physical blocks
Jun 25 16:08:07 hostname kernel: [181603.942357] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Test WP failed, assume Write Enabled
Jun 25 16:08:07 hostname kernel: [181603.943386] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Asking for cache data failed
Jun 25 16:08:07 hostname kernel: [181603.943393] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
Jun 25 16:08:07 hostname kernel: [181603.944506] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Optimal transfer size 33553920 bytes not a multiple of physical block size (0 bytes)
Jun 25 16:08:07 hostname kernel: [181603.948248] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
Jun 25 16:08:07 hostname kernel: [181603.948255] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense Key : Illegal Request [current]
Jun 25 16:08:07 hostname kernel: [181603.948257] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Add. Sense: Invalid command operation code
Jun 25 16:08:07 hostname kernel: [181603.960998] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
```

Specifically:

```
[…] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[…] Sense Key : Illegal Request [current]
[…] Add. Sense: Invalid command operation code
```

The device spins up fine mechanically with no unusual noises, but none of the partitions are being detected, and as a result, they don't show up in the file manager.

I don't think this matters much, but just to provide some context, it's an Ubuntu 20.04-based distribution (elementary OS 6.1 Jólnir) running on a Samsung Series 9.

Answer (score 0):

A confluence of circumstances led to the errors:

- according to the output of `sudo lshw -C bus`, my laptop has USB 3.0 ports (I was definitely plugged in to one of the SuperSpeed ports), and  [according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_3.0#Power_and_charging), **USB 3.0 is only capable of delivering 900 mA** to "SuperSpeed" devices
- the SATA-to-USB 3.1 adapter I was using (Sabrent [EC-331](https://web.archive.org/web/20230401071626/https://sabrent.com/products/ec-ss31)) uses host bus power only
- according to the [spec sheet for the hard drive](https://www.seagate.com/files/staticfiles/support/docs/samsung-ds/100698122c.pdf) (a Samsung-branded Seagate Momentus ST750LM022), **the spin-up current is 1000 mA**

The pedantic details of the USB specs aren't that important, nor whether that 100 mA power delivery mismatch would *really* make a difference during spin-up; it was just a hint that the device wasn't getting enough juice to initialize properly. Indeed, when I switched to a different (S)ATA-to-USB adapter, one with a power brick for mains power, the problem went away. The device spun up without errors, and all its partitions appeared in the file manager.

For comparison, this is what the device initialization looks like when the drive spins up properly:

```
Jun 25 16:12:50 hostname kernel: [181886.610640] scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ST750LM0 J9CCA04298       0001 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2 CCS
Jun 25 16:12:50 hostname kernel: [181886.611686] sd 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
Jun 25 16:12:50 hostname kernel: [181886.612554] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] 1465149168 512-byte logical blocks: (750 GB/699 GiB)
Jun 25 16:12:50 hostname kernel: [181886.613194] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
Jun 25 16:12:50 hostname kernel: [181886.613204] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 00 38 00 00
Jun 25 16:12:50 hostname kernel: [181886.613814] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Asking for cache data failed
Jun 25 16:12:50 hostname kernel: [181886.613826] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
Jun 25 16:12:50 hostname kernel: [181887.068846]  sdb: sdb1 sdb2 sdb3 sdb4 sdb5 sdb6 sdb7 sdb8
Jun 25 16:12:50 hostname kernel: [181887.071252] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
```

[This Tom's Hardware article](https://www.tomshardware.com/news/usb-3-2-explained#how-much-power-do-usb-3-2-and-usb-3-1-offer) suggests that I would have encountered the same problem even with a USB 3.1 or 3.2 capable laptop.

The fact is, it's simply an older device with a higher current draw, and bus power alone is insufficient to initialize the device.